# LWJGLException not found?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL version 2.9.1. I set up my Eclipse project with the following referenced libraries: lwjgl_util.jar, lwjgl.jar, and slick-util.jar. I also linked all of the necessary native .dll files for Windows. The file that is causing the error contains the following code:

```
package render;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

public class DisplayManager {
    
    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;  
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;
    
    public static void createDisplay() {
        
        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2);
        attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
        attribs.withProfileCore(true);
        
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // tell opengl where to render game (use whole display)
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT); 
        
    }
    
    public static void updateDisplay() {
        
        Display.sync(FPS_CAP); // ensures buttery smooth fps
        Display.update();
    }
    
    public static void closeDisplay() {
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

I am using this class in the following:

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import render.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        DisplayManager.createDisplay();
        
        // enter game loop until someone clicks the top right x button
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            // game logic and rendering
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
            
        }
        
        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above file, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 1 more
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is almost always caused by using an incompatible or incorrect version of LWJGL or the LWJGL library is not in your library folder or on the class path. Check which version is compatible with your other libraries or java version. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261193/lwjgl-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: How are you running the application? `NoClassDefFoundError` suggests that you don't have the right LWJGL jar files included in the classpath when you run the application.

Comment: Note that LWJGL uses both a jar and several dll files etc and they all need to be available and compatible, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063530/java-library-path-error

Comment: @Jesper That's a good point. I'm gonna be honest, I'm really new to Java and I was using VSCode for the last 2 weeks, so this is my first time setting up a project in Eclipse. I added all the jar files to the ModulePath but not to the ClassPath. Can you explain what the difference is? Thanks!

Comment: I don know because I have not used Eclipse for 10 years... The module path is probably for Java's module system, which is not used by many applications, so you should probably add the jar files to the classpath.

Comment: did you link the files to module path or class path? they need to be linked through classpath, also you said you linked the natives, are they addded to build path? or are they added as natives to the JAR files.         this looks just like thinmatrix's tutorials, I have a modern LWJGL 3 version of this class if you want it, works fine with the rest of the series as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 I'm alright for now, thanks though! You're also correct; I had added the jar files to the module path instead of the class path. Do you know what the difference is? I've been learning Java for the last two weeks and never come across the idea of modules. Are they an Eclipse specific thing? Also, what do you think of thinkmatrix's tutorial? Is it worth a watch? I just started it and I wanna make sure I'm not wasting my time. I just really want to learn opengl

Comment: @OniBarolli I think that modules were implemented as a way to add dependencies  easier, and with the dependencies being checked at compile time.  ThinkMatrix's tutorials were the best java OpenGL tutorials I could find, they are great for learning lwjgl, but they can be a little difficult sometimes. I would highly recommend GamesWithGabe's tutorials as well, they are both great. 
GamesWithGabe's tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyKE7vz65rY&list=PLtrSb4XxIVbp8AKuEAlwNXDxr99e3woGE&ab_channel=GamesWithGabe

Answer (score 0):

the solution from Zyfo worked for me.

right click the project -> build path -> configure build path -> import and move your lwjgl jar files under the classpath menu

[Screenshot of the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUe2.png)

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is go to the Build Path of your project and change the .jar files from under the Modulepath to be under the Classpath.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).